# Atlassian Confluence setup SQL Server database on MS Azure server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, confluence

I need an advice from you:

I'm trying to install Atlassian Confluence on Azure service.

I have an Ubuntu VM and a SQL Server there.

But, there is problem with the database connection setup.

The following error(s) occurred:

> Configuring the database failed. Couldn't create the database schema.
>   java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: DB server closed connection

Parameters:

- URL: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://pb9b4k5fgh.database.windows.net:1433; database=db;

Can it be a firewall problem?

Comment: You can try to verify the firewall from Ubuntu VM: `telnet pb9b4k5fgh.database.windows.net 1433`

Comment: Looks like it can't find SQL server.

Comment: if so, it may be the firewall issue. You need to go to Azure management console to open the firewall for the Ubuntu VM.

Comment: You mean you're using SQL Azure - the "SQL Server in the cloud" version - right? Because SQL Server doesn't run on Ubuntu ....

Comment: marc_s, yes, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

If you see that error it means that you are on SQL Server and you can't create schema for that specific database with current user credentials. I think you must grant DB_Owner right for user which you use to connect to SQL Server.